# Spring service automatic calling Oauth2 protected services

Tags: spring, redis, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have a service A which calls service B to get some resource. It works fine when a client calls A with access token and A will relay the token to the request to B.

Now, I am implementing redis to cache data. When I receive a message from B that something is updated, I need to call B to retrieve those updated resource. However, A does not have the access token now and my request is not authrized.

Is there a way to automatically generate an access token?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post some code. Without it, it is hard to know what you're actually doing and how to help. How are you receiving notice that something has updated? Is A calling B at set intervals to check for updates? Or are you using Netty to push data? Is a front-end calling back-end A at set intervals which then calls service B? Or is it some other setup? Posting code should help answer these questions and make it easier to help find you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got something to work, but not sure whether it is good practice.

I created a separate RestTemplate for this.

Dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Enable:

```
@EnableOAuth2Client
```

application.yml:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    auto:
      clientId: <client id>
      clientSecret: <client key>
      grantType: password
      username: <username>
      password: <password>
      accessTokenUri: <URI>
      userAuthorizationUri: <URI>
      scope: openid profile email
```

Configuration:

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.auto")
    protected ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails autoOAuth2Details() {
        return new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    }

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    protected OAuth2RestTemplate autoRestTemplate(RestTemplateCustomizer customizer) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(autoOAuth2Details);
        customizer.customize(restTemplate);
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Using this template my service is able to call other services by itself.